# in rust, How to store Polars.DataFrame(large amounts of data) to database(e.g: pgsql……)。

Tags: database, dataframe

In rust:
I tried using ConnectorX to read data from the database, but I don't know how to save dataframe data to the database.
Is there a good way to save it(Polars.DataFrame) to database(e.g: pgsql……)?
thank you (^_^)

I didn't find a good solution。

Comment: i have the same question